# Join text into one cell in various row and column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that has values that looks similar to below :

[image: raw data]

Is there any possible way to create VBA to join all the separate data together for each ID and Class into one row? So that the ending result would look like below?

[image: end result]

```
Sub JoinRowsData() 
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    lastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        For j = i + 1 To lastRow 
            If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(j, 2) Then 
                For k = 5 To 10 
                    If (Cells(i, k) = "" And Cells(j, k) <> "") Then 
                        Cells(i, k) = Cells(j, k) 
                    End If 
                Next 
            End If 
        Next 
    Next 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: thanks peh, im trying this code but seems doesnt get right :

Sub JoinRowsData()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    For j = i + 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(j, 2) Then
            For k = 5 To 10
                If (Cells(i, k) = "" And Cells(j, k) <> "") Then
                    Cells(i, k) = Cells(j, k)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Comment: That's no problem, of course you would not come here if it would do everything right. It is totally fine posting your non-working code. At least we see what you tried and can tell you where you got it wrong or where you need some improvement. Just [edit] your question show what you did and explain what went wrong (eg if you got errors and where) or what the code did versus what you expect it to do. Please don't post code as comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will do it. See the comments for an explanation how it works. It uses arrays to process the data which is much faster than process cells directly.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub JoinRowsData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet  ' define worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastRow As Long  ' get last used row in worksheet
    LastRow = GetLastUsed(xlByRows, ws)
    
    Dim LastCol As Long  ' get last used column in worksheet
    LastCol = GetLastUsed(xlByColumns, ws)

    ' Read data into an array for faster processing
    Dim Data() As Variant
    Data = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Value2
    
    ' define an output array with the same size
    Dim Output() As Variant
    ReDim Output(1 To UBound(Data, 1), 1 To UBound(Data, 2))
    
    Dim outRow As Long  ' output row index

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To LastRow  ' loop through all rows in data
        ' if column 1 contains data it is a new output row
        If Data(iRow, 1) <> vbNullString Then
            outRow = outRow + 1
        End If
        
        ' loop through all columns in a data row
        Dim iCol As Long
        For iCol = 1 To LastCol
            If Data(iRow, iCol) <> vbNullString Then ' check if current cell has data
                If Output(outRow, iCol) <> vbNullString Then
                    ' add a line break if there is already data in the output cell
                    Output(outRow, iCol) = Output(outRow, iCol) & vbLf
                End If
                
                ' add the data to the output cell
                Output(outRow, iCol) = Output(outRow, iCol) & Data(iRow, iCol)
            End If
        Next iCol
    Next iRow
    
    ' write all the output data from the array back to the cells
    ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Value2 = Output
End Sub


' find last used row or column in worksheet
Public Function GetLastUsed(ByVal RowCol As XlSearchOrder, ByVal InWorksheet As Worksheet) As Long
    With InWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            Dim LastCell As Range
            Set LastCell = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=RowCol, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False)
            If RowCol = xlByRows Then
                GetLastUsed = LastCell.Row
            Else
                GetLastUsed = LastCell.Column
            End If
        Else
            GetLastUsed = 1
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Peh,
this vb macro so complicated for me to create but you help me out :D